# Set naming strategy to lower camel case for one class

Tags: java, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

My project already has an ObjectMapper defined, as follows

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// some other settings here
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Most classes in my project in fact use `SNAKE_CASE`, and everything's peachy. Now I have a class that the downstream returns in lower camel case. I tried using `@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.LowerCamelCaseStrategy)` on my class. If it existed that'd work, but nothing like that seems to exist inside `PropertyNamingStrategy`.

All I find referencing lower camel case is the constant `PropertyNamingStrategy.LOWER_CAMEL_CASE` which is only used like in the top snippet it seems, and I definitely don't want to override the project settings here, since almost all classes use snake case.

Of course, I could slap a `@JsonProperty('propertyInLowerCamelCase')` on every property in the class, but there's quite a few, and that seems like it shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enforce lowerCamelCase, you can use the annotation

```
@JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy::class)
```

This enforces the default naming strategy (lowerCamelCase) and overrides a globally configured naming strategy.